# How to traverse an array and find all reachable points in C?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I've been thinking about how to find all the reachable points in an array from a given starting point Arr[x][y], where reachable points are points that values differ by no more than 2 from the current positions value. Then I want to return an array which has 1's in all reachable positions and 0's in unreachable positions.

Suppose Arr[6][6] looks like this:

```
10 11 14 18 20 20 
11 12 11 19 20 20 
24 28 12 15 18 31
44 46 13 12 57 30
42 45 10 14 59 31
38 42 46 16 16 23
```

Then the returned array would look like

```
1 1 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0
```

I'm thinking the best way to achieve this is to create a newArr and then have 4 different cases where I compare the current position to each of its neighbours, and then if they are reachable, set newArr[x][y] to a 1. Otherwise set it to a 0. Can someone explain how I determine where to move to next, and how to keep track of which points I've already tested?

Consider position [0][0] in the original array, after comparisons, since it is possible to move right or down, how do I decide? Or somehow do both?

Comment: do they help?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: The solution indicates that the 50 in row 2, column 3 (starting from row 1, column 1 at bottom-left) is reachable.  That means that diagonal connections count — the 52 in R3C4 is the only cell within 2 of the value 50.  So, you have to look in all directions, it would seem — up to 8 ways from the current cell.  However, the solution isn't entirely consistent; the 56 at R1C5 should be part of the solution unless there's an unstated rule about 'must be a different value from the current cell, but within 2 of the value in the current cell'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry I made a mistake when typing the result array. I think I fixed it now, but there are no diagonal movement allowed

Answer (score 4):

You might want to consider something like a [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm. Your "target color" would be the value of your starting point, and your "replacement color" would be any point within ±2 of the target. Rather than "painting" your data array, you instead want to mark the indices in the return array. `calloc` is good choice for initially zeroing out your return array.

After evaluating your starting point, you would evaluate the indices adjacent to that index. If an index has been marked as 1 in the array you're returning, you can ignore that index because it's already been covered by the algorithm.

Comment: A flood fill was my first idea, too.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right path. Yes, you need to check the neighbors. You make a decision based on the comparison with all 4 neighbors(or less depending on the location).

This is a typical BFS problem. Look [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).You start from one point, then go to the neighbor and do a check (which depends on the problem that you are solving), and update a result matrix and keep going on.

Typically a queue is used for implementing BFS. Here is the algorithm:

```
Set result [n][n] as all zero
Insert the beginning point (i,j) to a queue Q
result[i][j] = 1  // the starting point is reachable from itself
While queue is not empty:
  Take point (x,y) from Q 
     For each neighbor (z,w) of (x,y):  //which are north, south, east, west
       if (result[z][w] == 0 && | value[x][y] - value[z][w] | <= 2) {
          result[z][w] = 1
          push point(z,w) into Q
       }
```

[UPDATED 1]: Thanks for comment from @Jonathan Leffler for pointing out 8 neighbors, not 4, and the possible extra condition of `value[x][y] - value[z][w] != 0` that needs to be confirmed by @Shayna Grose

[UPDATED 2]: Reverting back. Per @Shayna Grose comment: Diagonal is not allowed (4 neighbors need to be taken into account) and the diff = 0 is OK.

Comment: Note that there seems to have been a 'glitch' (or pair of glitches) in the original solution matrix; diagonals aren't allowed and the solution point that required a diagonal was an error (and one solution point that didn't need a diagonal was omitted, another error).

Comment: What is the running time of this as a function of n? O(n^2)? @arash

Comment: @Newbie18 Yes in the worst case. Since we need to visit every location (in the worst case) and make 4 comparisons (except the edges that have 2 or 3 comparisons). So quadratic complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a DFS(Depth-first search)to slove this problems.and I think BFS  is also OK.
c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int row,col,x,y;
int a[6][6]={
50,51 ,54, 58, 60, 60,
48, 52, 51, 59, 60, 60, 
44, 48, 52, 55, 58, 61,
44, 46, 53, 52, 57, 60,
42, 45, 50, 54, 59, 61,
38, 42, 46, 56, 56, 63
};// the date
int vis[6][6];// the result
int dir[4][2]={
    1,0,0,1,0,-1,-1,0
};
void dfs(int x,int y){
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){  //4 direction
        int nx=x+dir[i][0];
        int ny=y+dir[i][1];
        if(!vis[nx][ny]&&abs(a[nx][ny]-a[x][y])<=2&&nx>=0&&ny>=0&&nx<6&&ny<6){
            vis[nx][ny]=1;
            dfs(nx,ny);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    vis[6][6]={0};
    scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
    vis[x][y]=1;
    dfs(x,y);
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<6;j++){
            printf("%d",vis[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When a question is tagged C, please do not provide a C++ solution.  The two languages are quite different, and what is appropriate in C is often not appropriate in C++, and what is appropriate in C++ is usually (or, at least, often) impossible in C.  People learning C often don't have the skills necessary to translate C++ into C.